Gauss-Jordan algorithm to solve a pyramidal puzzle
Preamble: Hello, this question comes from another (German) internet forum, and was asked to third-graders in elementary school. I had been looking for a systematic way to solve this question with my code (the system of equations).
My problem: I want to know if this system of equations, given as a pyramid:

where each cell is the result of adding the two cells below this cell, can be solved by applying the Gauss-Jordan algorithm - or if I need another approach.
My approach: (but there are always free variables included):
public class GaussJordan {
    private final double[][] matrix;

    public GaussJordan(double[][] matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    public void printMatrix() {
        for (double[] arr : matrix) {
            for (double d : arr) {
                System.out.printf("%.2f\t\t", d);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void process() {
        int k; // pivot
        double[] swapTemp;

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            k = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                if (matrix[j][i] > matrix[k][i]) {
                    k = j;
                }
            }

            if (matrix[k][i] == 0) {
                System.out.println("System of equations contains free variables");
                return;
            }

            // Swap the rows i and k
            swapTemp = matrix[i];
            matrix[i] = matrix[k];
            matrix[k] = swapTemp;

            // Iterate over all subsequent rows
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                // Reduce row by row
                if (i != j && !reduceRow(matrix[i], matrix[j], i)) {
                    System.out.println("System of equations cannot be solved by this app");
                    return;
                }
            }

            printMatrix();
        }
    }

    private boolean reduceRow(double[] r1, double[] r2, int pos) {
        if (r1.length != r2.length) {
            return false;
        }

        double factor = r2[pos] / r1[pos];
        for (int i = pos; i < r1.length; i++) {
            r2[i] -= factor * r1[i];
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GaussJordan(new double[][]{
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 47},
                {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39},
                {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 12},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5},
                {0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        }).process();
    }
}


Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed.

Welcome to MSE! Maybe show us the linear system corresponding to your problem. What are the conditions for the method to work?

I see you added some code, that's good. I see you introduced 10 variables, maybe it would be easier to only introduce the five you don't already know!

There are 5 unknowns, and there are 5 equations that they occur in (from the 5 three-cell subtriangles, excluding the 47+39=86 subtriangle) so you should be able set up a linear system of equations to solve.

It seems like you are treating $g$ and $j$ as variables too. So you actually need 7 equations whereas as you have only 5 in your code.

@Pranay Thanks, that was the point.

Cutting the Gordian Knot:
Count the number of paths up the pyramid from each element to the top. For instance there are three paths from $h$ to the top. It follows that the top number $86$ is actually a sum that uses three contributions from $h$.
Do this for all the cells in the array and you find that the path counts actually match the corresponding entries of Pascal's Triangle (P$\triangle$). Therefore, if you multiply each element in the array by the corresponding entry in P$\triangle$, the sum of the products in each row must match the top ($86$).
So $(1×12)+(3×h)+(3×i)+(1×5)=86\implies h+i=23.$
Now compute $e$, insert the result into the array and you can solve for everything else by difference.

Many thanks at @Pranay.
I have filled the equations to 7, and now the code can solve the system:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GaussJordan(new double[][]{
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 47},
                {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39},
                {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 12},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5},
                {-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
        }).process();
    }

End output:
1,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        24,00       
0,00        1,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        23,00       
0,00        0,00        1,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        16,00       
0,00        0,00        0,00        1,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        12,00       
0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        1,00        0,00        0,00        12,00       
0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        3,00        0,00        33,00       
0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        0,00        1,00        5,00

So, d=24 e=23 f=16 g=12 h=12 i=11 j=5.
